# How do I send a database I created in SQL to another person?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am working on a group project for school with several other classmates and I cannot figure out how to send them the database. I can locate the database in my file explorer, but when I try to send them the file over email, they cannot open it. I am using SQL Server management studio 2019

Comment: Where does the database **server** (instance) live?...You installed the server on your local machine?

Comment: Backup your database and send created backup files.

Comment: How, exactly, you are taking a copy, and how, exactly, are they trying to use it? The standard way is to do a backup & restore, but attaching a consistent copy of the db files and scripting are also options.